# How to preventDefault() when the tab or browser is closed in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there such event that fires when a tab or browser is closed?

I want to warn the user first if they are sure to quit and if no preventDefault().

This did not work:

```
angular.element($window).bind("beforeunload", function (event) {
    var response = confirm('Sure?');

    if(!response){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `confirm` when dealing with that event, you must return a string that will be used as a confirmation message :

```
angular.element($window).bind("beforeunload", function (event) {
    return 'Sure?';
});
```

[see the MDN on beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

Note that you have no real guarantee the user will see this confirmation dialog :

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to
>   confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the
>   event is displayed in this dialog. In Firefox 4 and later the returned
>   string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the
>   string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave -
>   data you have entered may not be saved." See bug 588292.
>
> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to
>   window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be
>   ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more
>   details.
>
> Note also that various mobile browsers ignore the result of the event
>   (that is, they do not ask the user for confirmation). Firefox has a
>   hidden preference in about:config to do the same. In essence this
>   means the user always confirms that the document may be unloaded.

The rationale is that a site should not make it difficult or painful to close the tab/window/browser.

Comment: aand it works only in Firefox, right? thanks for your answer, it explains everything

Comment: one more question: what would you do in such a case? let's say, a user is uploading something and they accidentally closed the tab or browser?

Comment: @Jahongir The usual practice is to make the process really clear : people are now accustomed to the fact things are broken when they close the window too soon, after all they already buy many things on internet.

Comment: so, let them close tab/browser and cancel whatever they were doing?

Comment: Yes, that's what people expect anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try :
```

jQuery(window).bind(
            "beforeunload",
            function () {
                return confirm("Do you really want to close ?")
            }
    );